# load a jquery function after docuemnt.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row">
            <div class="panel">
           <button type="button" class="reveal" onclick="DisplaySearchResults()">Show Search</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the corresponding javascript code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var $button = $('.displayButtons');

    $('#PetitionsSearch').keyup(function() {
        var re = new RegExp($(this).val(), "i"); // case-insensitive
        $button.show().filter(function() {
            return !re.test($(this).text());
        }).hide();   
    });
    });

    function DisplaySearchResults(){
        var s = '<input type="text" id="PetitionsSearch" placeholder="Type to search">'+
                '<br>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">AA1009</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">AA1010</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">BA1098</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">BB1890</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">C89761</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">CD1667</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">GG7830</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">GF6537</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">BH6537</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">HGB562</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">LK9063</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">CP9871</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">IRON87</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">ACT567</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">MPO760</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">GH5436</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">NBH894</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">GHFDF6</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">US4536</button>'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary displayButtons">MO9854</button>'+
                   '</div>';

         $(".panel").append(s)

    }
```

The interface looks like this after pressing the show search button[image]

The search doesn't work unfortunately and I am not sure how I can get it to work.I think the $(document).ready(function (){ }); has already been loaded after the show search button is displayed.
I am attaching the source files for easy working. excuse the sloppy coding. 
https://transfer.sh/VUyG8/test.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `$(document).ready` code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".panel").on('keyup', '#PetitionsSearch', function() {
    var $button = $('.displayButtons');
    var re = new RegExp($(this).val(), "i"); // case-insensitive
    $button.show().filter(function() {
      return !re.test($(this).text());
    }).hide();
  });
});
```

When your `ready` code runs, the `#PetitionsSearch` field does not exist yet. So you need to use `on` method of `jQuery`.

You can see this in action at this Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/qTJfBcrf98gzAektzujp

Answer (score 1):

the reason its not working is that you are attaching an `event listener` on 
`#PetitionsSearch` before appending it to the dom, hence it doesnt work.

try adding your code:

```
$('#PetitionsSearch').keyup(function() {
    var re = new RegExp($(this).val(), "i"); // case-insensitive
    $button.show().filter(function() {
        return !re.test($(this).text());
    }).hide();   
});
```

to the end of `DisplaySearchResults()` function instead of `$(document).ready`